# Get dependencies from another Makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to use multiple makefiles like this:

In `~/generator/Makefile`:

```
foo.xml: foo-part1.xml foo-part2.xml foo-part3.xml
    ./generate $^ > $@
```

And in `~/some/other/dir/Makefile`:

```
foo.xml:
    $(MAKE) -C ~/generator $@
    mv ~/generator/$@ $@
```

The problem is: when I go to `~/some/other/dir/` and run `make foo.xml`, there is no dependency list for `foo.xml`, and `make -C ~/generator foo.xml` isn't called even if (for instance) `~/generator/foo-part1.xml` is newer than the target.

The only solution I thought of is copying the dependency list with absolute paths to `~/some/other/dir/Makefile`, which is quite awful:

```
foo.xml: ~/generator/foo-part1.xml ~/generator/foo-part2.xml ~/generator/foo-part3.xml
```

Then, my question is: is there a way in a makefile to ask *another* makefile what are the dependencies of target? Or to just forward the request `foo.xml` to that makefile and collect the result? I basically want the second makefile to rely on the first one when it comes to decide if a target should be rebuilt, and when it comes to build it.

Comment: This class of problem is why the [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf) paper (pdf link) was written.

Comment: You could include one makefile from another, and then make your second target dependent on the first (so long as you don't have conflicting targets/variables in the two makefiles).

Comment: It's not clear that your existing solution isn't exactly what you want. You say you want the same dependencies in both makefiles, but then you say you want the first makefile to decide whether the target should be rebuilt-- which is what you already have.

Comment: @Beta Sorry if I was unclear, what I already have is a copy/paste of the dependency list with absolute paths. I would like to either tell the second makefile "ask this makefile for the dependencies of this target" or, even better, "tell this makefile to build this target according to it's dependencies" (without having to copy/paste the dependency list into the second makefile).

Comment: @EtanReisner I'll have a look at this paper, it may be that I went to the wrong direction indeed.

Comment: What does the second makefile need that list of dependencies *for?* It can call `$(MAKE) -C ~/generator $@` without knowing them, and the resulting sub-Make will read the first makefile and decide whether to rebuild `~/generator/foo.xml`. Does the second makefile have some other use for that list of dependencies?

Comment: @Beta's point is, and quite correctly, that unless you really need to avoid the execution of `make` in this flow your current makefile is fine. If you *do* want to avoid the extra invocation of make then that is where the recursive make issues come into play. It should be added that just because you run make doesn't mean you *need* to mv/cp the file. You can check contents against the local foo.xml and only copy when they differ so that running that make doesn't *always* trigger a local rebuild.

Comment: Oh, ok, I get the point. No indeed I don't mind the extra call to `make`, what was bothering me was the lack of proper dependency check in the second makefile (that's what I meant by "having the same dependencies"), but I think I understand what you said and what is the right way to do that: making `foo.xml` depend on `~/generator/foo.xml` and have a rule for `~/generator/foo.xml` that calls `$(MAKE) -C ~/generator foo.xml`, my error would have been to try to do that in only one rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by having two rules in the second makefile:

And in `~/some/other/dir/Makefile`:

```
.PHONY: ~/generator/foo.xml
~/generator/foo.xml:
    $(MAKE) -C ~/generator $(notdir $@)

foo.xml: ~/generator/foo.xml
    cp $< $@
```

Comment: I won't complain about the downvotes, I understand this question and the answer are far from exemplary, but could you give some feedback so I can improve my future questions and answers?