# How to check if a submake is up to date

Tags: makefile

Let's consider this files structure:

```
/project
+ Makefile
+ projectA
| + Makefile
| + foo.c
| + bar.c
| + ...
|
+ projectB
  + Makefile
  + oak.c
  + ...
```

How can I quickly check if a submake is up to date?

In my main make I have:

```
all: 
   make -C projectA
```

And in the submakefile

```
all: a.txt b.txt

%.txt:%.xtx
   cp $< $@
```

The problem with this solution is that I will always call the submake whatever it has nothing to do. I want to avoid it.

The ugly solution I've found is to create a make rule in my submakefile to echo all the files that are depending on the main target. Then I can call the submake with a shell command:

```
 listfiles=$(shell make -C projectA listfiles)
 all: $(listfiles)
    make -C projectA
```

**EDIT**

A better approach would be to have a shell script in each *sub-projects* that returns the list of all the project's dependencies. For instance:

projectc/listdep.sh:

```
 #!/usr/bin/bash
 find . -iname *.[ch]
```

Then I can use this script in the parent make:

```
 projectc/a.out: $(shell projectc/listdep.sh)
    make -C $(dir $@)
```

In this way, the parent make won't call the recipe if `projectc/a.out` exists and is more recent that its dependencies.

Comment: Unless the cost of that extra make call is something you really need to avoid don't bother playing these games. (And in fact your ugly solution is, I believe, strictly worse than having done nothing as you will always run make once (even if that target doesn't need to be run) and in cases where you needed to run the sub-make in the first place you now run it twice.) The only *solution* to this problem is to not use recursive make in the first place. Which is what the [Recursive Make Considered Harmful paper](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf) is all about (pdf link).

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26718564/258523) for some discussion about this.

Comment: Read the manual for `make`. Hint: at least on GNU `make`, there is a command line option (`make -q`) that simply tests if something needs to be done or not...

Comment: @twalberg Good point but how can I use it in the parent Makefile?

Comment: You don't want to use `make -q` in this situation.  Consider: if `make -q` returns "not up to date", what do you want to do?  You want to run `make`.  And if `make -q` returns "up to date", then you've already run make and it wouldn't have done anything anyway, even if you hadn't given `-q`.  So, best case you do the same work and worst case you do twice the work.  Just run the `make` in the subdirectory.  There's nothing more efficient (except using non-recursive makefiles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope your `projectA` and `projectB` are "self-contained".  That means, their builds do not read any sources or build intermediate files from outside that project.  They may use tools, such as `gcc` or, as you have it in the example above `cp`, but not sources outside of their directory, and not any files that are built by somebody else.  In other words, if you deleted the whole rest of the tree and only build `projectA` and `projectB` by themselves with their `Makefile`s, they will build just fine.

In such a case, it is OK to use recursive Make.

If you use recursive Make, you have to do what you are doing,

```
make -C projectA
```

There is no better way.  That is the best way to "quickly check" if the "submake" is up to date.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that I don't check the dependencies. With `projectC: \n $(MAKE) -C projectC/` make doesn't know if the target i.e. `projectc.out` and all its sources i.e. `projectc.c``projectc.h` were modified since the last build. So I will need to use this: `projectC/projectc.out: projectc/projectc.c projectc/projectc.h \n $(MAKE) -C projectc/`. In this case the best solution should be `projectc/projectc.out: $(shell make -C projectC get_src_list) \n make -C projectc/`. What do you think ?